# Unexpected unpack results with bit strings

Tags: ruby, unpack

Why is it that when I open up irb and I run
`puts 'A'.unpack("B8")`
I get `01000001` but when I run
`puts 'A'.unpack("B4B4")`
I only get `0100` and not `[0100,0001]`?

Is the resolution of unpack only a full byte? Nothing less?

Comment: The Ruby docs are a bit vague. However, Ruby's `pack` and `unpack` are pretty much straight copies from Perl and [Perl's `B`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) says "descending bit order *inside each byte*" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do some tests to understand the behavior:

```
> 'A'.unpack('B8')
 => ["01000001"]
```

It returns the 8 Most Significant Bits (MSBs) of char `'A'`

```
> 'A'.unpack('B4')
 => ["0100"]
```

It returns the 4 MSBs of char `'A'`

```
> 'A'.unpack('B16')
 => ["01000001"]
```

It returns the 16 MSBs of char `'A'`, but as there is only 8 we get the 8 MSBs

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B16')
 => ["0100000101000010"]
```

It returns the 16 MSBs of the sequence of chars `'AB'` (the end 8 Bits `01000010` corresponds to `'B'`)

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B10')
 => ["0100000101"]
```

It returns the 10 MSBs of the sequence of chars `'AB'`, i.e. the 8 MSBs of `'A'` and the 2 MSBs of `'B'`

```
> 'ABC'.unpack('B*')
 => ["010000010100001001000011"]
```

It returns all the MSBs of the sequence of chars `'ABC'`, (the end 8 Bits `01000011` corresponds to `'C'`)

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B8B8')
 => ["01000001", "01000010"]
```

It returns the following array:

- the first element is the 8 MSBs of the char `'A'`
- the second element is the 8 MSBs of the char `'B'`

_

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B8B7')
 => ["01000001", "0100001"]
```

It returns the following array:

- the first element is the 8 MSBs of the char `'A'`
- the second element is the 7 MSBs of the char `'B'`

_

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B4B8')
 => ["0100", "01000010"]
```

It returns the following array:

- the first element is the 4 MSBs of the char `'A'`
- the second element is the 8 MSBs of the char `'B'`

_

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B16B8')
 => ["0100000101000010", ""]
```

It returns the following array:

- the first element is the 16 MSBs of the sequence of chars `'AB'`
- the second element is empty as the chars have already been consumed

_

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B*B8')
 => ["0100000101000010", ""]
```

It gives you the same result, and consume all the string.

```
> 'AB'.unpack('B9B8')
 => ["010000010", ""]
```

It returns the following array:

- the first element is the 9 MSBs of the sequence of chars `'AB'`
- the second element is empty as the chars have already been consumed

## As conclusion,

the directive `BN` over a String will consume at most the first `((N-1) / 8) + 1` chars of the String. If there is still chars in the string, and you have a second directive `BM`, you'll consume at most the next `((M-1) / 8) + 1` chars of the String. And so on for all the next directives. If you use the directive `B*`, it will consume all chars, and returns the sequence of their corresponding MSBs.

For instance:

```
'ABCDEFG'.unpack('B17B*B8')
```

It should returns us:

- the 17 MSBs of the sequence `ABC`
- all the MSBs of the sequence `DEFG`
- an empty bitstring

Let's check:

```
> 'ABCDEFG'.unpack('B17B*B8')
 => ["01000001010000100", "01000100010001010100011001000111", ""]
```

And indeed `'A'.unpack('B4B4')` returns the array `["0100", ""]` as the first directive consumes the char `A`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the leg work! I understand now. I was expecting it to unpack literally bit by bit and only consuming half the character if requested. I didn't consider the directive consuming the entire character in the string.